# little Issue with babylonjs scene border

Tags: html, css, babylonjs

I  have a small issue with my babylonjs scene. When I click a mesh in the scene a border appears (in my browser the border is blue but it differs depending on the browser):

[in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLhpf.jpg)

[a friends browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMG8L.png)

this is the html/css code of my component (I use vuejs):

```html
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="Rahmen">
      <div id="textblock">
        <h1 id="welcome">Willkommen</h1>
        <h4 id="welcome-text">
          Planen Sie mit unserem Konfigurator einfach und
          schnell Ihre individuelle Containertreppenl&oumlsung
        </h4>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span>So klappt's</span>
          <b-button pill id="popover-help-button"><v-icon id="popover-help" name="question-circle" /></b-button>
          <b-popover ref="popover"
                     target="popover-help-button"
                     triggers="hover"
                     placement="top">
              Wählen Sie bitte aus wie viele Container sich in Ihrer Containeranlage in Höhe und Breite befinden.
            <img src="@/assets/helpp1.gif" width="440" />
          </b-popover>
      </div>
        <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas> <!-- babylon scene-->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#renderCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.wrapper {
  position: center;
}

.Rahmen {
  padding-top: 7%;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#textblock {
  padding-left: 7%;
  position: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#popover-help {
  color: blue;

}
#popover-help-button {
background: transparent;
border: transparent;
left: 0%;
margin-left: 0%;
margin-top: 0.5%;
}
.popover {
  max-width: 450px;
}

</style>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.It caused by `tab-index`.

https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/remove-border-of-rendering-canvas/16074

Answer (score 0):

Would an extra CSS line like `outline:none;` help you out?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.